# What is the template for this slide?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I was wondering what it is the template for [this slide](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/papers/slides.pdf)? I guess it is written with `beamer`, but don't know how the slides are so fancy. So is there some tutorial on writing this particular slides among others?

Comment: Only now I noticed that there is a link to my website. I have used `\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}`. You can find some example for this package online: https://www.google.com/search?q=beamerthemesplit&tbm=isch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like `Copenhagen` from [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). Consider scrolling through the [`beamer` theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html) or the [`beamer` theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/).

Since this is only a theme change, you construct the presentation like you would any normal presentation in `beamer`, and just change the theme to `Copenhagen`. See the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for the steps to create a presentation.

Comment: Another useful site is the [Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)

Comment: @Seamus: You're kidding me, that's awesome! I'll add it to my answer, for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, Werner! The two sites (the beamer theme gallery and the beamer theme matrix) are great. I wonder if it is possible to go to the source code by clicking an example on either of the two sites? That will be fantastic but I only get pictures.

Comment: I would suggest creating the sample presentation given at the start of the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). Then just change the themes to see how the presentation changes. Also of interest might be [Beamer by example](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-4/mertz/mertz.pdf). Or, read [this tutorial](http://www.uncg.edu/cmp/reu/presentations/Charles%20Batts%20-%20Beamer%20Tutorial.pdf), or the [`beamer` source examples](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/src/4a510a8c7341/examples) page. The latter includes code, of course.